# Pasar Array como parámetro a una función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¡Hola a todos!

Bien, yo tengo una clase llamada *Options*, el cual tiene a su vez un método llamado *add*:

```
class Options {
 add(a,b,c,d){
 }
}
```

También, tengo un array llamado *P*:

```
var P = [
 ["Ta","Te","Ti","To"]
]
```

Creo mi objeto de la clase Options:

```
var Ready = new Options();
```

Ahora, aquí viene mi pregunta, ¿cómo puedo hacer para pasar el índice 0 de mi array *P* como argumento a mi nuevo objeto creado, usando el método *add*?

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero no funciona:

```
Ready.add(P[0]);
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que, al ejecutar mi programa, el parámetro de *Ready.add();* tome exactamente los strings de mi array **P**. Es decir, de la siguiente manera:

```
Ready.add("Ta","Te","Ti","To");
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: No me queda nada claro lo que estás diciendo, eso de pasar `P[0]` y luego decir que quieres pasar los componentes del *array* ... En cualquier caso, creo que [el operador spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes, creo que deberias llamar el método así: Ready.add(P[0][0],P[0][1],P[0][2],P[0][3]);

Comment: El comentario de @Trauma indica el buen camino. Yo además te preguntaría, ¿por qué P es un array con un array? Parece una complicación necesaria puesto que las cadenas de texto están en P[0][i] en lugar de estar en P[i], que parece ser lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, `P` es un array multidimensional (un array dentro de otro array), por lo que no deberías escribir `Ready.add(P[0]);` sino `Ready.add(P[0][0]);`.

En cambio, si `P` fuera un array de una dimensión:

```
var P = ["Ta","Te","Ti","To"]
```

Deberías utilizar el [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) de esta forma:

```
Ready.app(...P)
```